# Python authlib JWT algorithm used validation

Tags: python, jwt, authlib

Im creating a flask web app with the python module [authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/). My question is about the verification of received JWTs in a route wrapper. When I verify the token and it's payload I am not quite sure how to make sure that it is signed with the correct HS256 algorithm and not set to none to bypass security altogether. I could not understand how to do this only from the [documentation for JWT prodivded for this library](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc7519.html#authlib.jose.rfc7519.JWT.decode) 
My current draft of the wrap for restricted routes:

```py
def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = get_token_auth_header()
        claim_options = {
            "iss": {
                "essential": True,
                "values": issuers
            },
            "aud": {
                "essential": True,
                "values": audiences
            },
            "exp": {
                "validate": JWTClaims.validate_exp,
            },
            "sub": {
                "essential": True
            },
            "is_admin": {
                "essential": True,
                "values": [True,False]
            },
            "is_moderator": {
                "essential": True,
                "values": [True,False]
            }
        }

        try:
            #TODO set an option here or something to check alg in token?
            claims = jwt.decode(token, secret,claims_options=claim_options)
        except InvalidTokenError as e:
            raise AuthError({"code": "invalid_token",
                "description": "token is invalid"}, 401)
        except BadSignatureError as e:
            raise AuthError({"code": "bad_signature",
                "description": "token signature is bad (does not match payload/tampered payload/wrong secret)"}, 401)
        except ExpiredTokenError as e:
            raise AuthError({"code": "token_expired",
                            "description": "token is expired"}, 401)

        #is this needed or how to do this better with the library used?
        if claims.header["alg"] == None or claims.header["alg"] != algorithm:
            #prevents auth stripping/setting auth to none attacks and attacks setting from rsa to hs256 and encrypting public key
            raise AuthError({"code": "bad_signature",
                            "description": "signature algorithm given does not match algorithm expected"}, 401)           

        try:
            claims.validate()
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except MissingClaimError as ex:
            raise AuthError({"code": "missing_claim",
                            "description":
                                "claim is missing"}, 401)
        except InvalidClaimError as ex:
            raise AuthError({"code": "invalid_claims",
                            "description":
                                "incorrect claims,"
                                "please check the audience and issuer"}, 401)
        except ExpiredTokenError as e:
            raise AuthError({"code": "token_expired",
                            "description": "token is expired"}, 401)
    return decorated
```

Comment: `from authlib.jose import JsonWebToken` and initialize `jwt = JsonWebToken(['HS256'])`. If you try to decode a token signed with a different alghoritm will be raise a **UnsupportedAlghorithmError**